# How do I get the correct value from a class object with a singleton class?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am working on an app that manages a list of boat in Eclipse. I need to use a singleton class to create and hold a list of boat objects. I also have to create a regular class for all of my accessors aka the methods to manipulate the data values stored in the data members of the class Boat. The problem I have is when I use the add method for the boat_list reference. It will only accepts the location and the Boat object, but when I run the app, it says only the fullname of the app package. It should says whatever data value that I stored in using the get method. Here is the code I have in my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Declare references and some variables
        BoatList boat_list;
        Boat boat1;
        String make;

        //Create a new Boat object
        boat1 = new Boat();

        //Input data value to some data members
        boat1.setMake("Sea Ray");
        boat1.setYear(2003);
        boat1.setRegi("D15F4");

        //Set the reference tv

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_main);

        //Access the singleton class, BoatList
        boat_list = BoatList.getInstance();

        //Put some strings into boat_list

        if (boat_list.isEmpty()) {
            //add item
            boat_list.add(boat_list.size(), boat1);
            boat_list.add(boat_list.size(), boat1);
            boat_list.add(boat_list.size(), boat1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onOption1(MenuItem i) {
        int x;
        BoatList boat_list;

        tv.setText("Show the Items in the List");

        //Get the list from BoatList
        boat_list = BoatList.getInstance();

        //Show each item in the list
        for (x = 0; x < boat_list.size(); x++)
            tv.append(boat_list.get(x) + ", ");
    }

    public void onOption2(MenuItem i) {
        tv.setText("Doing Option 2.");
    }

    public void onOption3(MenuItem i) {
        tv.setText("Doing Option 3.");
    }

    public void onOption4(MenuItem i) {
        tv.setText("Doing Option 4.");
    }

    public void onOption5(MenuItem i) {
        tv.setText("Doing Option 5.");
    }

    public void onOption6(MenuItem i) {
        tv.setText("Doing Option 6.");
    }

    public void onOption7(MenuItem i) {
        tv.setText("Doing Option 7.");
    }

    public void onOption8(MenuItem i) {
        tv.setText("...");
    }

    public void onOption9(MenuItem i) {
        tv.setText("...");
    }

    public void onOption10(MenuItem i) {
        tv.setText("...");
    }

    public void onOption11(MenuItem i) {
        tv.setText("...");
    }
}
```

Here is what my singleton class looks like:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public final class BoatList extends LinkedList<Boat> {

    private static BoatList instance = null;

    private BoatList() {
        // Exists only to defeat additional instantiations.
    }

    public static BoatList getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new BoatList();

        return instance;
    }
}
```

And, here is what my class Boat looks like:

```
public class Boat {

    //Declare data members
    private String make;
    private String registeration;
    private int year;
    private int length;
    private int beam;
    private String fuel;
    private double price;
    private String picURL;
    private int age;

    //Define the methods
    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String m) {
        make = m;
    }

    public String getRegi() {
        return registeration;
    }

    public void setRegi(String r) {
        registeration = r;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int y) {
        year = y;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(int L) {
        length = L;
    }

    public int getBeam() {
        return beam;
    }

    public void setBeam(int b) {
        beam = b;
    }

    public String getFuel() {
        return fuel;
    }

    public void setFuel(String f) {
        fuel = f;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double p) {
        price = p;
    }

    public String getPicURL() {
        return picURL;
    }

    public void setPicURL(String url) {
        picURL = url;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        //Calculate the age of the boat by the current year plus
        //the year that the boat was manufactured 
        int currentYear = 2015;

        age = currentYear + year;

        return age;
    }

    public double getLuxuryTax() {
        //Declare variables
        double newPrice;
        double luxTax = .15;

        if (length >= 50 && age <= 10)
            newPrice = price * luxTax;
        else
            return price;

        return newPrice;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singletons should not extend from anything. If you want this singleton to return a list of something then give it a list as a member and create functions to access them.

```
public final class BoatList {

    private static BoatList instance = null;
    private List<Boat> list_of_boats = new ArrayList<Boat>();

    private BoatList()
    {
        // Exists only to defeat additional instantiations.
    }

    public static BoatList getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new BoatList();

        return instance;
    }

    public List<Boat> getListOfBoats()
    {
         return list_of_boats;
    }

    public void addBoat(Boat boat)
    {
        list_of_boats.add(boat);
    }
}
```

Also, you might want to try calling the toString() method of your Boat object when you print to the TextView, like this:

```
// I added the (int) in the declaration cause it was missing
for(int x = 0; x < boat_list.size(); x++)
    tv.append(boat_list.get(x).toString() + ", ");
```

Overriding the toString() method can also ensure that you are printing exactly what you want.

Comment: I did exactly how you could, but it is still not giving me the right output. I want the singleton class to like "talk" with a regular class called Boat, and when I use the get method (regular built-in method for a List), it should return the data value that is stored in data member (for example, year) in the class Boat.

Comment: When you call the get() method of a list, it will return an object of that list, in this case an instance of a Boat object. To get the year of that Boat object, you would have to call getYear() on that instance of Boat to get the year. Is this how you're using it? What is the return value of getYear()?

Comment: I think you said in your comment is what I have been looking for, but how do I do that? In other word, how do I code it? As you see in my question above, I created a seperate regular Class Boat. So, how do I call any methods, like getYear() on that instance of Boat? Plus, I have still having trouble with storing a boat object into the list because when I use the get method for the list (boat_list.get(x)), I just get the full package name of my app (com.example.appproject1.Boat@b31856b8). How do I fix that?

Comment: Just add a get method after the get(x) like this: boat_list.get(x).getYear(). The value you're returning if you don't add another get afterwards is the this: (fully qualified class name)@(instance ID). This is the default return value of the toString() method of a Java Object. If you override this function in the Boat class, you can make it return a formatted String that looks any way you want. For instance, you can make it return "Make: [make], Model: [model], Year: [year]".

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, and I should have known that I could use the get method of the object right after I use the get method for the list. I did not thought of that. Again, thank you!